# Finding all possible combinations of array items that add to combination of items in other array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have two arrays having huge number of items, nearly millions items. I need to find out all the combinations of elements from array 1 summing to the individual elements or combinations of elements in array 2. The number of elements to be combined is variable. 
Ex: Array1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    Array2 {5,8,10}

Matching 1 item from Array1 to item in array2 gives

5 =>5

8 =>8

Combining 2 items from Array1 with 1 item in array2 gives

1,4 =>5

2,3 =>5

2,6=>8

1,7=>8

3,5=>8

6,4 =>10

7,3 =>10

8,2 =>10

9,1 =>10

Combining 2 items from Array1 with 2 items in array2 gives

9,4=>5+8

8,5=>5+8

7,6=>5+8

9,6=>5+10

8,7=>5+10

and so on for combining 3 items.
I need to write a code to achieve this?Has anybody already faced such problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a jolly good requirement.  You can do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have an array with only 1000 elements, and you want to consider each combination of 100 elements from the array. How many combinations would you need to process?

Well, it's given by the formula for number of combinations:

```
C = N!/(K!(N-K!)
```

where N = 1000 and K = 100.

So C = 1000!/(100!*900!) = (approx) 6.4*10^139

This is a very big number, and its totally impossible to go through all these combinations in any reasonable time. (Even if you could process a million combinations per second, it would take many more times the current age of the universe.)

This is only a subset of the problem that you describe, and furthermore your arrays have nearly a million elements.

Therefore the answer to your question is: This is not possible.